# Достать уникальные значения при отношении Многие-Ко-Многим

Tags: java, hibernate

Представим, что у нас есть два `POJO` класса. Класс `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
    //...
```

И класс `Group`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    //...
```

Пытаюсь достать 50 пользователей, которые не в группе с `id=2`. Делаю следующим образом:

```
Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.createAlias("groups", "groups", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.setMaxResults(50);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
criteria.list();
```

Но так как между двумя сущностями отношение `Многие-Ко-Многим`, то пользователи в результате запроса повторяются. Как достать 50 уникальных пользователей?

**P.S.** `DISTINCT` и `ORDER BY` использовать нельзя, так как к `USER` таблице  `JOIN`'ятся еще 3 таблицы (но, к счастью, там отношение `Один-Ко-Многим`).